# Xcode 6 Interface Builder centre multiple labels in middle of view

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, interface-builder, xcode6

I'm writing an iOS app which has multiple labels in one view, like shown:

[image: Labels Example]

I would like these labels to be in the vertical centre of the view, with the middle of the collection of labels as the centre of the view.

I need to use auto layout for this, as the top label may be multiple lines, or may only be one depending on input, and will change height depending on this.  This, along with the top label being a different size, means that I cannot simple have the middle label in the middle, and the others relative to that.

I'm looking for a solution either in code or IB.

---

EDIT: To clarify, I am looking to centre the middle of multiple labels, like so:
[image] 
(The vertical middle might be slightly off)

*The image should read vertical middle

Comment: @mohacs That question is regarding aligning a single label to the centre.  I want to align the centre of a collection of labels to the centre of the container.  I have now edited the question to avoid confusion

Comment: @mohacs Yes, because I'm not looking to centre any one label.  I'm looking to have the vertical middle of the collection of labels in the vertical middle of the container.  To clarify, I mean the vertical middle to be as shown in the image above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old question of mine, but it maintains a fair number of views, and is quite a common use-case.  I do not feel the other answer is a very efficient method to achieve this.

The easiest method to centre a collection of views is to place them within a `UIView` object which is itself centred.

To use the example above, the three `UILabels` would be within one `UIView`, with a `0` constraint between the top and bottom labels and the View.  The view itself would then be set to be centred vertically.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do this with Auto Layout, but you can code.  I'm assuming you've already figured out the spacing of the labels, so I'll just help you center the whole thing.

```
var o1 = label1.frame.origin
var o4 = label4.frame.origin
var h4 = label4.frame.height
var w4 = label4.frame.width
var hc4 = o4.y + h4
var wc4 = o4.x + w4
var screen = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height
var remainingScreen = (screen - (hc4 - o1.y))/2.0
var screenW = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
var remainingScreenW = (screenW - (wc4 - o1.x))/2.0
var moveH = remainingScreen - o1.y
var moveW = remainingScreenW - o1.x
var frame1 = label1.frame
var frame2 = label2.frame
var frame3 = label3.frame
var frame4 = label4.frame
label1.frame = CGRect(x: frame1.origin.x + moveW, y: frame1.origin.y + moveH, width: frame1.width, height: frame1.height)
label2.frame = CGRect(x: frame2.origin.x + moveW, y: frame2.origin.y + moveH, width: frame2.width, height: frame2.height)
label3.frame = CGRect(x: frame3.origin.x + moveW, y: frame3.origin.y + moveH, width: frame3.width, height: frame3.height)
label4.frame = CGRect(x: frame4.origin.x + moveW, y: frame4.origin.y + moveH, width: frame4.width, height: frame4.height)
```

This whole thing isn't very self explanatory, but I won't talk about what every line does.  The overall idea is it finds the distance between the upper left and lower right corner of all the labels (so UL of label1 and LR of label4 [this only works if you've already set the spacing between labels and the width/height of each label]), then it finds the width/height (W/H) of the screen and subtracts the W/H of the label area, divides by two, giving the space between the top of the screen and the labels.  Finally, it finds the distance the entire assembly needs to move by comparing the UL corner with where it should be, and combines the amount to be moved with the original location of all the labels.

Note:  This code could be heavily condensed, it is just easier to view and read if it is written like this.

Comment: So the origin of the label is the upper-left corner?

Comment: Yeah...  This code might not be right.  Nothing is happening for me.

Comment: I believe this code is theoretically correct, but frame.origin is returning incorrect numbers for me.

Comment: Oh right, I haven't had a chance to test it yet - I'm away from my dev PC for the day - but I'll try it tomorrow